# PHO Hidden field using ran

Tags: php, random

What would the right syntax of something like this be? I am trying to insert a hidden field that generates a random string

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="mt_rand(5, 15) )">';
```

Comment: `<?= mt_rand([...]) ?>` or `<?php echo mt_rand([...]) ?>`

Comment: that title's unclear, as is the post.

Comment: @Script47 Only when my wife throws me a certain "look" ;-)

Comment: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="'.mt_rand(5, 15).'">';`

Comment: @Script47 That and the "you had better get out of this room **now** if you know what's good for you" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  mt_rand(5, 15) inside **value="mt_rand(5, 15)"** won't be interpreted.


**mt_rand** is a PHP function which generates a random value (the function does not generate a cryptographically secure value).

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="'.mt_rand(5, 15).'">';
```

Here is a possible implementation of a function which generates random strings:

```
//$num_chars : number of characters to generate.
//$case: upper case or lower case

function randomString($num_chars, $case){
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $result = '';
    if(strtoupper($case) == "L"){
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_chars; $i++){
            $result .= $chars[mt_rand(0,35)];
        }
    }
    elseif (strtoupper($case) == "U"){
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_chars; $i++){
            $result .= strtoupper($chars[mt_rand(0,35)]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: what could I use to generate a random string of characters?

Comment: @user1915410 You could use Google or any other search (including the one here) to find that answer.

Comment: you need a custom function to achieve that.

Comment: don't worry, we all had to start somewhere, i edited the answer and included an implementation, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="test" value="'.rand(5, 15).'">';
```